# Silently create perforce client from command line

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I need to create perforce clients from my jenkins build scripts, and this needs to be done unattended. This is mainly because jenkins jobs run in unique folders, Perforce insists that each client has a unique root target folder, and we create new jenkins jobs all the time based on need. Right now each time I create a unique jenkins job, I have to manually create a perforce client for that job - I can do this from the command line, but Perforce also insists on pausing the client creation to show me the specification settings file, which I need to manually close before the client is created.

To create the client I'm using

```
p4 -u myuser -P mypassword client -S //mydepo/mystream someclientname
```

and I'm using this awful hack to simultaneously kill notepad

```
p4 -u myuser -P mypassword client -S //mydepo/mystream someclientname | taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F
```

This sort of works, but it doesn't feel right. Is there an official/better way I can force p4 to silently force create a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
p4 -u user -P ticket client -S //depot/stream -o someclientname | p4 -u user -P ticket client -i
```

Comment: Thanks @sam-stafford, that did it. I changed the position of the -o switch, P4 expects it to strictly follow stream name.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare client form upfront and pass the path by:

```
p4 client -i newClientForm.txt
```

I guess that you can have a script that prepare such file before calling `p4 client`.

Take a look on the default form that is popping up every time.

I don't know how you can deal with passing both options `-S` and `-i` though.

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach. First create the client using this technique, then switch it to the stream in question. You won't get prompted for any form input if you do it this way.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex I'm afraid - I don't want to have to maintain a text file with client info.